# SQL Server: Update ranking on a scheduled basis

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, row-number

The following table is made up of jobs and their respective "ranks":

```
N   PO      Status
1   110217  Planned
2   110217  Planned
3   108999  Planned
4   108999  Planned
5   108999  Planned
6   108999  Planned
7   110225  Planned
8   110219  Planned
9   110219  Planned
10  110235  Planned
11  110236  Planned
12  110047  Planned
13  110048  Planned
```

I have a different application that I am using to update the `Status` column to "completed" once the job is done. I call a stored procedure on a nightly basis to update `N` to 0 for all jobs that have been completed that day. It looks like this:

```
N   PO      Status
0   110217  Completed
0   110217  Completed
3   108999  Started
0   108999  Completed
0   108999  Completed
6   108999  Planned
7   110225  Planned
8   110219  Planned
9   110219  Planned
10  110235  Planned
11  110236  Planned
12  110047  Planned
13  110048  Planned
```

So, originally, the `N` comes from an insertion from a different table that utilizes a window function. I would like to be able to update the ranking the next day to shift all remaining orders to their new positions. If I run this code here:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) AS N*, *
FROM MyData 
WHERE N <> 0
```

Then I get my desired result. Which is this:

```
N*  PO      Status
1   108999  Started
2   108999  Planned
3   110225  Planned
4   110219  Planned
5   110219  Planned
6   110235  Planned
7   110236  Planned
8   110047  Planned
9   110048  Planned
```

The problem is that I cannot update a table column using a window function. Are there any workarounds for this? Is it possible to mimic the logic of `ROW_NUMBER()`? A view here is not possible, as the third party application I use does not work with SQL Views.

One last thing note: the dataset here is for one specific category. My data has several categories that all need this same logic to occur, so I would also need the `PARTITION BY` functionality of `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.N = T.New_N
FROM 
(
    SELECT N, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) AS New_N
    FROM updated_status_table
    WHERE N <> 0
) T
```

You can also use CTE to do the update like below:

```
;WITH CTE  AS
(
    SELECT N, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) AS RN
    FROM updated_status_table
    WHERE N <> 0
)
UPDATE CTE SET N = RN
FROM CTE
```

Please see the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f81daf0e96196c18486f27f0e973e94)**.

P.S. You can alwasys add `partition by` as per your requirement.

Comment: Brilliant! Are there any performance issues with either? The data I'm using is relatively small-scale.

Comment: @sykfarhan Thanks! I think that depends on many factors, but the query optimizer will use the best plan and I think both the approaches are providing the same thing to the optimizer. I would prefer to use CTE as it gives the option to query/check the data further if required.